# Elasticsearch Painless script for the average aggregation based on date difference and one of the date is from params maps

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to calculate the average aggregation based on date difference.
Earlier both the date were in the same index, so tired this for the average index:

```
    "avg": {
            "script": {
              "source": "(doc['lastFixed'] - doc['firstFound'])/ (1000*60*60)",
              "lang": "expression"
            }
          }
```

but now the I have the 2nd date as HashMap in java and trying to pass that as param. I have around 100 entries in the map with the id and it's date.

Is there any way to iterate the HaspMap in painless script and check the Id of HashMap with the document Id and if they matches then calculate the combined average aggregation for all Ids with their dates.

I am trying with this painless script :

```
"for(entry in param.dataset.entrySet())"+
      "{if (item.getKey() == doc['id'])"+
      "{ (doc['lastFixed'] - item.getValue())/ (1000*60*60) }"+
  "}"
```

But I am not sure will calculate the combined aggregation for all Ids and their dates. as we are not saving or returning anything from the for loop iteration.

Please help me on this

Comment: I will suggest to do this math / calculation at indexing time and store in new seperate field and use that new field for aggregation which will fast compare to this.

Comment: can you two sample documents and your HashMap along with expected result

Comment: @SagarPatel I am not sure that the above solution will work as it not sending correct result.

Comment: @RushikeshSabde I am suggesting to do the calculation at index time and store output to the seperate field and used that field for aggregation.

Comment: @RushikeshSabde are userid unique in hashmap?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Yes the userId are unique in hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple return in your if condition will give difference per document.

I have tried to simulate hashmap in my query below. Change is only to add "return" in if condition. Let me know If I have not understood your question correctly

**Query**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "avg": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
                      Map map = new HashMap();
                      map.put("1","2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
                      map.put("2", "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");  
                     
                      for(entry in map.entrySet())
                      {
                        if (entry.getKey() == doc['userId.keyword'].value)
                        {
                          return (doc['updatedAt'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli() -  ZonedDateTime.parse(entry.getValue()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())/ (1000*60*60); 
                        }
                      }
                      
                      return 0;
                  """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @RushikeshSabde  does above work for you.

Comment: I have an array which contains the `doc['lastFixed']`  so i am using the `nest-path-aggr-namevulnerabilities` to do the aggregation on all of these `lastFixed` dates.

Comment: @RushikeshSabde I couldn't understand your comment. Can you please explain in detail

Comment: Actually I am performing aggregation, my Elasticsearch index  document contains an array of objects which have the lastFixed date under `vulnerabilities` key Thus I am using `nest-path-aggr-namevulnerabilities`. So in simple terms I have HashMap multiple key-values pairs and then Elasticsearch contains an array multiple `lastFixed` date with their respective Id.